# How do I filter jsonb with multiple criteria?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb
);
```

And the following data (partial for brevity...notice the randomness of years and the sales/expense yrs don't align with each other):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (data)
VALUES
('{"employee": "Jim Romo", 
 "sales": [{"value": 10, "yr": "2012"}, {"value": 5, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 40, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 2, "yr": "2007"}, {"value": 1, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2014"}], 
 "product": "tv", "customer": "1", "updated": "20150501"
}'),
('{"employee": "Jim Romo", 
 "sales": [{"value": 10, "yr": "2012"}, {"value": 5, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 41, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 2, "yr": "2009"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2014"}], 
 "product": "tv", "customer": "2", "updated": "20150312"
}'),
('{"employee": "Jim Romo", 
 "sales": [{"value": 20, "yr": "2012"}, {"value": 25, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 33, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 8, "yr": "2012"}, {"value": 12, "yr": "2014"}, {"value": 5, "yr": "2009"}], 
 "product": "radio", "customer": "2", "updated": "20150311"
}'),
('{"employee": "Bill Baker", 
 "sales": [{"value": 1, "yr": "2010"}, {"value": 2, "yr": "2009"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 3, "yr": "2011"}, {"value": 1, "yr": "2012"}, {"value": 7, "yr": "2013"}], 
 "product": "tv", "customer": "1", "updated": "20150205"
}'),
('{"employee": "Bill Baker", 
 "sales": [{"value": 10, "yr": "2010"}, {"value": 12, "yr": "2011"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 4, "yr": "2011"}, {"value": 7, "yr": "2009"}, {"value": 4, "yr": "2013"}], 
 "product": "radio", "customer": "1", "updated": "20150204"
}'),
('{"employee": "Jim Romo",
 "sales": [{"value": 22, "yr": "2009"}, {"value": 17, "yr": "2013"}, {"value": 35, "yr": "2014"}],
 "expenses": [{"value": 14, "yr": "2011"}, {"value": 13, "yr": "2014"}, {"value": 8, "yr": "2013"}], 
 "product": "tv", "customer": "3", "updated": "20150118"
}')
```

For each employee I need to evaluate the most-recently updated row and find employees with 2014 tv sales greater than 30. From there I need to further filter for employees with average tv expenses of less than 5. For the average I just need to take ALL of their tv expenses and not just the latest row.

My expected output would be 1 row:

```
employee    | customer | 2014 tv sales   |  2013 avg tv expenses
------------+----------+-----------------+----------------------
Jim Romo    |    1     |   40            |  4
```

I can (kindof) do 1 or the other but not both:

a. Get 2014 sales > 30 (but unable to get their most recent "tv" sales ;(

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (SELECT (a->>'value')::float FROM
    (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'sales') as a) as b 
    WHERE a @> json_object(ARRAY['yr', '2014'])::jsonb) > 30
```

b. Get the avg 2013 expense (this needs to be avg tv expenses)

```
SELECT avg((a->>'value')::numeric) FROM  
  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'expenses') as a FROM mytable) as b
  WHERE a @> json_object(ARRAY['yr', '2013'])::jsonb
```

EDIT: This will potentially be a very large table so any commentary on performance and indexing needs would be appreciated as I am new to both postgresql and jsonb.

EDIT #2: I've tried both answers and neither seem to be efficient for a large table ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (rather lengthy) answer to your problem. The comments inside the query should explain the different pieces. The basic ideas that I followed are: 1) keep simple each operation, try first to produce the correct result, then optimize; 2) trasform as much as possible (but not to much) the json structure in a more "relational like" structure, since relations have more powerful operators that json data in postgres. Of corse there is space to simplify the query and even produce a more efficient version, but at least this is a starting point.

```
with mytable1 as   -- transform the table in a more "relational-like" structure (just for clarity)
  (select id, data->>'employee' as employee, data->>'product' as product, 
      (data->>'updated')::integer as updated, (data->>'customer')::integer as customer,
          data->'sales' as sales, data->'expenses' as expenses 
   from mytable),
avg_exp_for_2013_tv as -- find the average expenses for tv in 2013 for each employee
   (select employee, avg(expenses.value) as avg2013_expenses
    from mytable1 , jsonb_to_recordset(expenses) as expenses(yr text, value float)
    where product = 'tv' and expenses.yr = '2013'
    group by employee),
most_recent_updates_employees as  -- find the most recent updates for each employee 
   (select employee, max(updated) as updated
    from mytable1 t1
    group by employee),
most_recent_updated_rows as   -- find the rows with the most recent updates
   (select t1.*
    from mytable1 t1, most_recent_updates_employees m
    where t1.employee = m.employee and t1.updated = m.updated),
employees_with_2014_tv_sales_gt_30 as
   (select employee, customer, sales.value as sales_value
    from most_recent_updated_rows m, jsonb_to_recordset(m.sales) as sales(yr text, value float)
    where yr = '2014' and value > 30)
select e1.employee, e1.customer, e1.sales_value as "2014 tv sales", e2.avg2013_expenses as "2013 avg tv expenses"
from employees_with_2014_tv_sales_gt_30 e1, avg_exp_for_2013_tv e2
where e1.employee = e2.employee and avg2013_expenses < 5
```